# How to configure spark thrift user and password

Tags: apache-spark

i am trying to connect spark thrift server by beeline, and i started spark thrift as below:

```
start-thriftserver.sh --master yarn-client --num-executors 2 --conf spark.driver.memory=2g --executor-memory 3g
```

and the spark conf/hive-site.xml as below:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
        <value>jdbc:node001:3306/hive?useSSL=false</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
        <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
        <value>NONE</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hive.server2.thrift.client.user</name>
        <value>root</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hive.server2.thrift.client.password</name>
        <value>123456</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hive.server2.thrift.port</name>
        <value>10001</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hive.security.authorization.enabled</name>
        <value>true</value>
        <description>enableor disable the hive clientauthorization</description>         
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
        <value>hive</value>
    </property>            
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
        <value>123456</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

when i use beeline cli to access spark thrift server, it hint me input username and passwd, but i didn't input anything, just click enter(no input the username and password configured in hive-site.xml), i also can access spark. How can make the configuration work well.

Thanks :)

```
beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://node001:10001
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://node001:10001
Enter username for jdbc:hive2://node001:10001: 
Enter password for jdbc:hive2://node001:10001: 
18/12/06 16:13:44 INFO Utils: Supplied authorities: node001:10001
18/12/06 16:13:44 INFO Utils: Resolved authority: node001:10001
18/12/06 16:13:45 INFO HiveConnection: Will try to open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://node001:10001
Connected to: Spark SQL (version 2.4.0)
Driver: Hive JDBC (version 1.2.1.spark2)
Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
0: jdbc:hive2://node001:10001> show databases;
+-------------------------+--+
|      databaseName       |
+-------------------------+--             |
| default                 |
| test                    |
+-------------------------+--+
7 rows selected (0.142 seconds)
0: jdbc:hive2://node001:10001>
```

Comment: do you get solution for mentioned issue?